# Display.ashx not displaying image name with character &

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a situation where Display.ashx displays successfully images from Sql server with only letters(e.g Coffee or Green tea) in it but when a image name is saved as (Coffee & Froth) it does not display.please see code below,i placed a break point on Img in Display class and when the imagename is Coffee the full string is passed but when the image name is Coffee & Froth it cuts the froth and only takes Coffee,meaning it takes only the string before the character &.can someone please please show me a workaround so it takes the whole string with the character.Thanks

```
 public class Display : IHttpHandler
    {
        public Stream Displays(string Img)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
            {
                string sql = string.Format("select top 1 img from Images where Name  = '{0}'", Img);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection.Open();

                object imagevalue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (imagevalue != null && imagevalue != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    return new MemoryStream((byte[])imagevalue);
                }

                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/noimage.png")))
                {
                    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                    memStream.SetLength(fs.Length);
                    fs.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fs.Length);
                    return memStream;
                }
            }
        }
    #endregion
```

This is how i call the Image

```
 protected void Refresh_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // string id = CoffeeMenu.SelectedValue;
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Display.ashx?id=" + "Coffee & Froth";
            divSuccess.Visible = false;
          divError.Visible = false;
        }
```

HTML

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="CoffeeMenu" runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Refresh_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

Comment: Try `"Coffee &amp; Froth"`. Or `"Coffee%20%26%20Froth"`   Also log\print the sql to check what is being sent to the database

Comment: Thank you @Mike67,replacing the string with "Coffee%20%26%20Froth" works fine.if i may ask a quetsion,what %20%26%20 exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Encode the data part:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Display.ashx?id=" + Server.UrlEncode("Coffee & Froth");
```

The problem you have is that an & is used to split values in a url so extra parameters for your display would look like:

```
?name=blah&resize=1920x1080&convert=png&rotate=90
```

As such your "Coffee & Froth" is probably being requested by the browser as Coffee+&+Froth and is being received and interpreted by your ashx as having these parameters:

```
{
  "id": "Coffee ",
  " Froth": null
}
```

---

Or, strip anything that's not a number or letter out of the filename; looks like you're in control of the naming of these things as they're stored on disk so make life simple

Answer (score 0):

(moving comment to answer)

Try `Coffee &amp; Froth` or `Coffee%20%26%20Froth`

`&amp;` is used in HTML to represent `&`

`%20` is hexadecimal for `space` and `%26` is hexadecimal for `&`. Hexadecimal is often used to encode special characters in URLs.

Full ASCII table:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters